# Filter NSSet of MKAnnotations using coordinates and NSPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nspredicate, mkannotation

I have an `NSSet` of `MKAnnotation`s obtained by:

```
NSSet *locationSet = [map annotationsInMapRect:map.visibleMapRect];
```

And then I write a `NSPredicate` to pass the desired latitude and longitude like this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"coordinate.latitude == %f AND coordinate.longitude == %f", coord.latitude, coord.longitude];
```

Now I try to get the desired object by filtering the set:

```
NSSet *filtered = [locationSet filteredSetUsingPredicate:predicate];
MKAnnotationSubClass *mark = [[filtered allObjects] lastObject];
```

But get an error saying that my object have not the key I passed:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key latitude.'`

What is the right way to filter this `NSSet` of annotations using latitude and longitude arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CLLocationCoordinate2D` is not key value coding-compliant, so you can't use the `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:]` method on this object (for filtering by its properties).

Use `[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:]` instead and you'll get the same result.

Comment: Indeed, `CLLocationCoordinate2D` isn't even an object, it's a struct.

Comment: yep, but generally it's important to know errors like this happens on any object/struct that is not KVC compliant.

Comment: I'm saying that structs cannot be KVC compliant; only objects can.

Comment: Exactly it! Thanks bro!